# Ошибка сохранения последнего значения при разносе DataSet и DBEdit по разным формам

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird

У меня две формы (*Form1* и *Form2*),
На Form1 расположены компоненты:

> IBDataSet, DataSource

На Form2 расположены компоненты:

> Компоненты набора DBComboBox и в DBEdit и т.д

Когда я заполнил все *DBEdit*'ы и вношу значение в последний компонент, допустим *DBEdit* и нажимаю кнопку "Post" на *DBNavigator*, то запись сохраняется, без посленего значения, который я внес в последний *DBEdit*.
Значение может сохранится, если после заполненния последнего *DBEdit*, мышкой стать на любой другой компонент *DBComboBox* и в *DBEdit*, и уже потом нажать кнопку "Post" на *DBNavigator*.

А также значение может сохранится, если я *IBDataSet*, *DataSource*, перенесу на *Form2*.

Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался? И как можно от это ошибки избавится, **оставив** все компоненты на обеих формах?

Спасибо

Comment: сделайте так. POST используйте через свою кнопку. И когда нажимается post переведите режим edit. и закройте режим edit.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответ, день потратил, но нашел...
У меня в *DBNavigator*, для поля с паролем стояла вот эта строка (у меня в *DBGrid*, поле с паролем отображается "*")

```
procedure TFPeople.dbnavPeopleBeforeAction(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TNavigateBtn);
begin
  dbedPassword.Field.EditMask := '';
end;
```

без нее работает все как нужно

Ща, вспомнить только зачем я ее туды засунул... дело то давненько было..

И как она, действует на окончание редактирования (ведь я вообще не то поле редактировал) ? 
Изменения, происходили ведь до "BeforePost" :)